# Plot histogram of a specific set of data based on date

Tags: r

For my study i need to plot histograms of my data based on date.

I'm working with the `hist()` function. In this function i want to plot the Distance from the specific days but i can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried

```
WPTD2 %>% 
  filter(Date==44915) %>% 
  hist(WPTD2$PerpDist)
```

but i get the error code:

```
Error in hist.default(., WPTD2$PerpDist) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Lookin at my data the data PerpDist is displayed as numeric.

Plotting the whole dataset with `hist(WPTD2$PerpDist)` is no problem.

I can't utilise ggplot because the next step of my research research requires me to utilise `hist()` for plotting detection models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure your data is numeric. After that if you want to use `hist` in a pipe, you could use `pull` to get the column you want and assign it to the function like this (example with iris dataset):

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  filter(Species == "virginica") %>% 
  pull(Sepal.Length) %>%
  hist()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

When you pipe with `a %>% foo(b)`, it is equivalent to `foo(a, b)`. So your code is interpreted like this:

```
## your code as written
WPTD2 %>% 
  filter(Date==44915) %>% 
  hist(WPTD2$PerpDist)

## your code as interpretted
hist(filter(WPTD2, Date == 44915), WPTD2$PerpDist)
```

Hopefully that makes your problem more apparent - you filter your data frame, and then give the filtered version of the whole data as well as an unfiltered version of `PerpDist` to `hist()`, which doesn't make sense.

`hist()` doesn't want a data frame at all--it just wants a column. You can use the `pull()` function to extract a column from a data frame in a `%>%` pipe, essentially a piped version of `$`. Using this, try

```
WPTD2 %>% 
  filter(Date==44915) %>% 
  pull(PerpDist) %>%
  hist()
```